# NSSingleObjectArrayI error when JSON Parsing in iOS?

Tags: ios

In My code when I am Parse the API I got the error like the __NSSingleObjectArrayI has nil, but is the Array have Values.

Here I Gave my Part of Code..

```
latitudeArray = [monumentArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
        NSLog(@"latitudeArray is %@",latitudeArray);
        longitudeArray = [monumentArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
        NSLog(@"longitudeArray is %@",longitudeArray);

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {

            CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latStr doubleValue] longitude:[longStr doubleValue]];
            CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] longitude:[[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]; ----------> This Line I Got The Crash Error..

            CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];
            NSLog(@"distanceInMeters is %f",distanceInMeters);
            float i  = distanceInMeters/1000;
            NSLog(@"distance between two places is %f KM", i);

            //[locationDistances addObject:distanceInMeters];
        }
```

What is the meaning of NSSingleObjectArrayI?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Please help me for resolve it.

The latitudeArray has values...

```
latitudeArray is (
    (
            (
                    (
                            (
                "27.1753210000",
                "27.1798189999",
                "27.1928780000"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

)

Comment: did you use this array in tableview ?

Comment: No just I got Response from API and Stored in Array..@KKRocks

Comment: Could you please show some code, what results the crash?

Comment: put code of initialisation of array.

Comment: are getting values in latitudeArray and longitudeArray?

Comment: Your error is not about "nil", it's about out of bounds. Your array have no values ([0,0]). Which one cause the crash? Is it due to a async issue?

Comment: yes, bur array have values@Larme

Comment: yes i got values in both array@Vinodh

Comment: get the double values separate double variable and print it. then check weather its printing or not. double lat=[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]; and double long=[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]; then print those values.

Comment: please check count of latitudeArray and longitudeArray . it should be equal to your for loop's limits .

Comment: When I see the log of `latitudeArray`, clearly it seems to be some issue. There is array inside array inside array, etc. Too much level. Guess? Culprit could be the use of `valueForKey:`, or not understanding some data structure of your JSON.

Comment: What returns "NSLog(@"Count: %d , %d", [longitudeArray count], [latitudeArray count]);" ?

Comment: It shows Count in Both array is 1,1.@Kerberos

Comment: Yes It too much level and confused@Larme

Comment: @saravanakumar: Your issue is more about the parsing. Please, try to check the parsing. Because currently, your `latitudeArray` is more like that: `@[@[@[@[@[@"27.1753210000",@"27.1798189999",@"27.1928780000"]]]]]` (at one "subarray" level more or less)  instead of `@[@"27.1753210000",@"27.1798189999",@"27.1928780000"]` (what you assume it is).

Comment: ok thanks i will check@Larme

Comment: Thanks I solved That@Larme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]` or `[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]` has not enough items at the time you try to access it at a particular index.

What you can do, to avoid the crash, is before you would access the object at a particular index, you check, if the count if the array is not bigger than the value of `i`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        if ([latitudeArray count] > i &&   [longitudeArray count] > i) {
            CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latStr doubleValue] longitude:[longStr doubleValue]];
            CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] longitude:[[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]];

            CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];
            NSLog(@"distanceInMeters is %f",distanceInMeters);
            float i  = distanceInMeters/1000;
            NSLog(@"distance between two places is %f KM", i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.@dirtydanee

Answer (score 8):

First to clear up some confusion: NSSingleObjectArray is just a special case of NSArray for arrays with a single element; happens quite a lot and having a special, smaller object for that case saves space. (There is even a class for empty arrays with a singleton instance; all empty arrays are the same object!). So pretend it is an NSArray.

The exception says clearly that you tried to access an array element that didn't exist. You tried to access the element at index 1, when your array had only one element, so only the element at index 0 could be accessed.

It seems quite obvious that you expect longitudeArray to have three elements, but it has only one. And I bet that monumentArray isn't an array, so don't call it in array.

When you process JSON, you *must* check that the data you received is what you expected, otherwise your app *will* end up crashing all over the place if your server doesn't send you exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (latitudeArray.count == longitudeArray.count) {
        for (int i = 0; i<latitudeArray.count; i++) {

        }
    }
```