# Unable to use TTTAttributedLabel framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel, tttattritubedlabel

I am using `TTTAttributedLabel` to make `UILabel` hyperlink, I am trying to do this as below:

```
 NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"By tapping you agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy."
                attributes:@{
            (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                                                                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16],
                                                                                 NSKernAttributeName : [NSNull null],
                                                                                 (id)kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor
                                                                                 }];

// The attributed string is directly set, without inheriting any other text
// properties of the label.
self.tttTermAndCondition.text = attString;
self.tttTermAndCondition.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)

//self.tttTermAndCondition.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked
self.tttTermAndCondition.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
NSRange range = [self.tttTermAndCondition.text rangeOfString:@"Terms of Use"];
[self.tttTermAndCondition addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range];
```

This shows perfectly fine but when i click the Term Of Use,

The TTTAtributedLabel crashes in its - (NSArray *) links method, It becomes a zombie object.

I dont know what exactly i am missing.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you show the crash report

Comment: Yes sure, Give me a moment.

Comment: This is what i get when i click *** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI valueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x178010a40

Comment: see  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396819/nssingleobjectarrayi-error-when-json-parsing-in-ios

Comment: Well i am using library which is running good with others so i don't think ill have to do any changes in their library, Its for sure that i am doing something wrong in using it.

Comment: did you implement : - (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url ?

Comment: this code working fine from my side..

Comment: U have a TTTAttributedLabel in .Xib or you are creating it and adding it from code?

Answer (score 0):

hello i put your code in my sample application its work fine just add the delegate method and your code work fine

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
tttTermAndCondition = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)];
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"By tapping you agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy."
                                                                attributes:@{
                                                                             (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                                                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16],
                                                                             NSKernAttributeName : [NSNull null],
                                                                             (id)kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor
                                                                             }];

// The attributed string is directly set, without inheriting any other text
// properties of the label.
tttTermAndCondition.text = attString;
tttTermAndCondition.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)

//self.tttTermAndCondition.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked
tttTermAndCondition.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
NSRange range = [tttTermAndCondition.text rangeOfString:@"Terms of Use"];
[tttTermAndCondition addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range];
//self.se
[self.view addSubview:tttTermAndCondition];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:nil completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding tttTermAndCondition in view? It is already inside .xib.

Comment: @uzairdhada i am just testing your code so i put the label in my viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes i can understand that, but i am trying to do it by .xib. I mean the label has been placed in Xib and has its object created in .h so in that way its not working.

Comment: its work fine with storyboard. can check where you set the name of Class in property to TTTAttributedLabel instead of UILable

Comment: Yap That also is fine. Did u install the framework using cocoapods?

Comment: no i just copy the .h and .m file of TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: Yes even i did same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142467/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-uzair-dhada).